# How install AIDE on Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-gnome

I have a question about AIDE (Advanced Intrusion Detection Environment):
I have Ubuntu and during the installation of AIDE from the terminal I have to do a Postfix Configuration. It's normal? How can I do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your Question lacks actionable details. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: We don't know your release (you've tagged Ubuntu-GNOME, so this is either a really old release of Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS being the last supported version but it's EOL now, or a modern release of Ubuntu Desktop but which release?), and you've not provide clues as to what you downloaded  and thus installed at terminal, with no copy/paste of that output or links as to where it came from. Being specific allows us to provide useful advice.

Comment: As far as I remember (haven't used AIDE for over a decade), AIDE wants to send e-mails when triggered, and defaults to using Postfix (which was fashionable when AIDE oroginated). Prowl through the AIDE documentation (or the source) to see if you can change it

Comment: You're right, sorry. The version is Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
Anyway, I think that @waltinatore answered me. I didn't understand why I was being asked to do the setup, but now it's clear to me.
Maybe I'm looking for an alternative to AIDE.
A thousand thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"apt install aide" will install the aide subsystem. No, you do not have to configure postfix. The important directories are "/etc/aide" for config files and "/var/lib/aide" for the aide database.

Initialize aide:

```
aide -c /etc/aide/aide.conf --init
```

Check or compare file system against aide database:

```
aide -c /etc/aide/aide.conf --check
```

Update aide database after a "check":

```
aide -c /etc/aide/aide.conf --update
mv /var/lib/aide/aide.db.new /var/lib/aide/aide.db
```

These are the bare minimum commands required for proper operation. You will want to suppress some directories as there are some directories that will be continually changing during normal Ubuntu/Linux operation. You suppress directories by making entries to the end of the aide config file (/etc/aide/aide.conf) like so:

```
!/tmp
!/var/spool
```

Those are just examples and you will also want to suppress other directories from being checked. I will leave that as an exercise for those interested or I will add comment below for those who are lazy.

When I personally run aide, I always switch to the database directory (/var/lib/aide). Be forewarned however this is not a quick process. On my production server hosting 5 websites it takes about 27 minutes.

Additionally you can run aide against specific file systems or directories as opposed to "everything". I will also leave that as an exercise for those interested.

It's a pretty easy subsystem to maintain and 99% of the time I only use the commands above (the "check" & "update"). When aide is initially installed and configured it will enter a cron job (/etc/cron.daily/aide) which will run at 0645. This is configurable via "/etc/aide/aide.conf".

There will invariably be someone who will say "No, don't use the /etc/aide/aide.conf file. Make a copy and use that." To that I say this: "I use aide on a daily basis and have found this is the most efficient way for me to use it on a per host basis".

That should cover completely the answer the OP's question. I'm a bit of a self complained expert on aide as I do use it daily but as there really isn't much to it you can truly learn it in a day and master it in a few days use. Then, read the man page for all the other things aide can do.

Final caveat, all these instructions are based on the current version of aide in the Ubuntu's repositories tested and running on Ubuntu 20.xx and 22.xx.